# Show button only if the person is admin otherwise disable the button

Tags: php

I have the login page now.When we login as a user or admin it redirects to the home page.
My question is when the person log in as a an admin i need to display all the button in home page and when the person log in as a user i need to disable the buttons.How can i do????Please help me:
Below is the code:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "select * from tbl_login where username = '$username' and password = '$password' ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

$_session["username"] = "username";
$_session["password"] = "password";
//$_SESSION['status'] = $var_value;

$info = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($info['status'] == 1)
{
    header("location:home.php");

}
elseif($info['status'] == 0)
    header("location:home.php");

}

else {

echo "Wrong Username or Password";

}
?>
```

The home page where buttons are included are:

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="" >
<tr>
    <td><input  name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"  >

    <td> <a href="insert.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']?>"></a><input  name="edit" type="submit" id="edit" value="edit"  ></td>

    <td><a href="insert.php?id=''" ><input type="button" value="Insert" /></a></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Comment: First and Most Important: you are prone to SQL injection. Solution: Store the user status in  [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) and in `home.php` generate buttons according to session

Comment: you need to assign a new session variable like $_SESSION['is_admin_logged'] and set it to true. put that inside the if($count==1) statement then from the other page (which contains the buttons) you can use that session variable to know whether this user is an admin or not and based on that do the show and hide thing and for more info your code is vulnerable and can be hacked easily you need to use mysql_real_escape_string() function to filter the $_POST variable and  escape sql injections.

Comment: i m little bit confused can anyone help me by doing me  the coding

Comment: `$_session` is different from `$_SESSION`

Comment: ok can u help me with full detail of coding???????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to assign a new session variable like `$_SESSION['is_admin_logged']` and set it to true. put that inside the `if($count==1)` statement then from the other page (which contains the buttons) you can use that session variable to know whether this user is an admin or not and based on that do the show and hide thing and for more info your code is vulnerable and can be hacked easily you need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` function to filter the `$_POST` variable and escape sql injections.

here is an example as requested:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$sql = "select * from tbl_login where username = '$username' and password = '$password' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1)
{
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

    $info = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($info['status'] == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION['admin_is_logged'] = true;
    }

    header("location:home.php");
}
else 
{
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

in home.php do something like this:

```
//this section will be shown to the logged in user only
if($_SESSION['admin_is_logged'])
{
    echo "Hey I'm the admin and my username is: ".$_SESSION["username"]."<br />";

    echo '<form name="frm" method="post" action="" >
    <tr>
       <td><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"  ></td>
       <td> <a href="insert.php?id='.$rows['id'].'"></a><input name="edit" type="submit" id="edit" value="edit"  ></td>
       <td><a href="insert.php?id=" ><input type="button" value="Insert" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    </form>';


}
```

Comment: Thank u admin for helping but i think u didn't get my question.When i log in as an admin i need to display edit,delete and insert button in home page and whenever i log in as simple user the buttons should not be displayed.Can u again help me with the coding?????

Comment: I got your question and the solution I wrote is exactly what you arelooking for. All you need is to use the $_SESSION['admin_is_logged'] variable to show or hide those buttons. also you can echo the buttons htmls from there. its simple...

Comment: What to do when the if($info['status'] == 0) there is nothing like that in the code

Comment: i'm assuming $info['status'] contains a flag whether the user is a simple user or admin right? if that's so then you need to check the updated code.

Comment: also you need to destroy the session cookies whenever you try to test this script because session cookies will be alive till you close the browser OR you destroy it from the server.

Comment: Cn u help me with coding where status==0